# Listens for custom messages on the production Bitcoin blockchain

Tags: java, bitcoin, blockchain

The application listens for OP_RETURN messages on the Bitcoin blockchain and prints them to standard output. OP_RETURN is a custom transaction locking script that can store data, but nothing beyond that. It's used for experimental use cases such as [proofofexistence.com](http://proofofexistence.com/) and [coinprism.com](https://www.coinprism.com/).

I would like some critical feedback, specifically code correctness, code smells, and my usage of the [bitcoinj](https://bitcoinj.github.io/) library. It's currently compatible with Java 6, but I would be interested in recommendations on Java 8 specific features that could streamline the use case.

Sample Invocation:

> java -jar target/ostendo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Output:

> ```
> +--------------------------------------------+---------------------+     
> | Hex Value                                  | UTF-8 Value         |   
> +--------------------------------------------+---------------------+   
> | 69643b6a65666662657a6f732e6964             | id;jeffbezos.id     |   
> | 69643b6c61727279706167652e6964             | id;larrypage.id     |   
> | 69643b6a6f686e656c746f6e2e6964             | id;johnelton.id     |   
> | 69643b6a6f6e726f6d65726f2e6964             | id;jonromero.id     |   
> | 6a134153435249424553504f4f4c30315049454345 | ASCRIBESPOOL01PIECE |
> ```

The full transaction is output to a log file for reference.

If you would like to build and execute the application, it's available at [GitHub](https://github.com/lifeofreilly/ostendo).

### Ostendo.java

```java
package com.gmail.lifeofreilly.ostendo;

import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException;

class Ostendo {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Ostendo.class);

    /**
     * A command line application for listening to OP_RETURN output messages on the Bitcoin blockchain.
     * This application leverages the production network. To use the test network, please see:
     * https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/NetworkParameters.html
     *
     * @param args none
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue();
        OPReturnListener OPReturnListener = new OPReturnListener(messageQueue);

        try {
            PeerListener peerListener = new PeerListener(OPReturnListener);
            peerListener.start();
            log.info("Listening for OP_Return messages...");
            System.out.println("Additional information is available at: " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/logs/error.log");

            String leftAlignFormat = "| %-60s | %-30s |%n";
            System.out.format("+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+%n");
            System.out.printf("| Hex Value                                                    | UTF-8 Value              |%n");
            System.out.format("+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+%n");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    String message = messageQueue.takeMessage();
                    System.out.format(leftAlignFormat, message, hexToUTF8(message));
                } catch (DecoderException e) {
                    log.error("Unable to decode the message: " + e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error(e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
        } catch (BlockStoreException e) {
            log.error("Failed to initialize the blockchain: " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Converts hex to a UTF-8 string
     *
     * @param hex the string to decode
     * @return the decoded string
     * @throws DecoderException
     */
    public static String hexToUTF8(String hex) throws DecoderException {
        return new String(Hex.decodeHex(hex.toCharArray()));
    }

}
```

### MessageQueue.java

```java
package com.gmail.lifeofreilly.ostendo;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

/**
 * A simple blocking message queue
 */
class MessageQueue {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    /**
     * Add a message to the queue to be processed.
     *
     * @param message the message.
     */
    public void addMessage(final String message) {
        messageQueue.add(message);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the head message in the queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.
     *
     * @return the message.
     */
    public String takeMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        return messageQueue.take();
    }


}
```

### PeerListener.java

```java
package com.gmail.lifeofreilly.ostendo;

import org.bitcoinj.core.BlockChain;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;
import org.bitcoinj.core.PeerEventListener;
import org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup;
import org.bitcoinj.net.discovery.DnsDiscovery;
import org.bitcoinj.params.MainNetParams;
import org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException;
import org.bitcoinj.store.MemoryBlockStore;

/**
 * A bitcoin network peer configured to use a custom listener
 * This leverages the production network. To use testnet please see:
 * https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/NetworkParameters.html
 */
class PeerListener {
    private static final NetworkParameters NET_PARAMS = MainNetParams.get();
    private final PeerEventListener peerEventListener;

    /**
     * Sole constructor for PeerListener
     *
     * @param peerEventListener the custom peer event listener you would like to use
     */
    public PeerListener(PeerEventListener peerEventListener) {
        this.peerEventListener = peerEventListener;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a bitcoin network peer and begins to listen
     *
     * @throws BlockStoreException
     */
    public void start() throws BlockStoreException {
        BlockChain blockChain = new BlockChain(NET_PARAMS, new MemoryBlockStore(NET_PARAMS));
        PeerGroup peerGroup = new PeerGroup(NET_PARAMS, blockChain);
        peerGroup.addPeerDiscovery(new DnsDiscovery(NET_PARAMS));
        peerGroup.addEventListener(peerEventListener);
        peerGroup.startAsync();
    }
}
```

### OPReturnListener.java

```java
package com.gmail.lifeofreilly.ostendo;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Block;
import org.bitcoinj.core.FilteredBlock;
import org.bitcoinj.core.GetDataMessage;
import org.bitcoinj.core.TransactionOutput;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Message;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Peer;
import org.bitcoinj.core.PeerAddress;
import org.bitcoinj.core.PeerEventListener;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Transaction;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A custom PeerEventListener that adds all OP_RETURN messages to a message queue
 */
class OPReturnListener implements PeerEventListener {
    private final MessageQueue messageQueue;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OPReturnListener.class);

    /**
     * Sole constructor for OPReturnListener
     *
     * @param messageQueue new messages will be added to this queue
     */
    public OPReturnListener(final MessageQueue messageQueue) {
        this.messageQueue = messageQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransaction(Peer peer, Transaction transaction) {
        for (TransactionOutput transactionOutput : transaction.getOutputs()) {
            if (transactionOutput.toString().contains("RETURN PUSHDATA")) {
                String message = extractMessage(transactionOutput.toString());
                messageQueue.addMessage(message);
                log.info("Found a message in Transaction: " + transaction.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeersDiscovered(Set<PeerAddress> set) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBlocksDownloaded(Peer peer, Block block, FilteredBlock filteredBlock, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChainDownloadStarted(Peer peer, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Peer peer, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDisconnected(Peer peer, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public Message onPreMessageReceived(Peer peer, Message message) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<Message> getData(Peer peer, GetDataMessage getDataMessage) {
        return null;
    }

    public static String extractMessage(String transactionOutput) {
        return transactionOutput.substring(transactionOutput.indexOf("[") + 1, transactionOutput.indexOf("]"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I want to talk about is:

> ```
>         while (true) {
>             try {
>                 String message = messageQueue.takeMessage();
> ```

This loop **smells**. Instead of using your custom class delegating to BlockingQueue, your messages can be handled by standard java library classes.

Also I'd expect a thread interruption to cancel the currently running thread instead of just being logged as error and then carrying on like before.

As such you might prefer to handle the `InterruptedException` in the outer try-catch, just like `BlockStoreException` by terminating the program.

If you switch to an actual `BlockingQueue` the `MessageQueue` class becomes completely obsolete.

---

> ```
>  * This leverages the production network. To use testnet please see:
>  * https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/NetworkParameters.html
> ```

I'd want this JavaDoc to link to the relevant class javadoc instead of an external link like follows:

```
* This leverages the production network. To use testnet please see {@link NetworkParameters}
```

This makes it available for offline inspection, if you have the relevant javadoc on the classpath (as you should have anyways...)

---

> ```
>         String leftAlignFormat = "| %-60s | %-30s |%n";
>         System.out.format("+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+%n");
>         System.out.printf("| Hex Value                                                    | UTF-8 Value              |%n");
>         System.out.format("+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+%n");
> ```

many things wrong here...

1. leftAlignFormat should be at the very least final, at best a private static constant
2. Your calls to `printf` and `format` are nonsensical and rely on a certian console width to be presented correctly.
   Instead use `System.out.println` to present this as independent as possible of your console.

Additionally you may want to encapsulate your printing logic into a separate class, which takes a `PrintStream` as input.

Consider the following:

```
TablePrinter printer = new TablePrinter(System.out);
printer.printHeader();
// loop header and then
    printer.print(messageQueue.take());
```

---

It may be interesting to simplify reading your `OPReturnListener` by having it extend a `NoOpListener` that overrides all methods with an empty declaration. This would get rid of the clutter from being required to Override methods you do not use.

---

Some more nitpicks:

- You use some IMO unnecessary intermediate variables. You can get rid of `message` in `OPReturnListener` and in `main`
- variable names should be camelCased, ergo:

  ```
  OPReturnListener opReturnListener = new OPReturnListener(messageQueue);
  ```
- the if-condition with `contains("RETURN DATA")` might be better off as a  separate method (may be overkill), but at least the string should be a constant

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review. I incorporated all feedback. This indeed helped to simply the code quite a bit. Updates are available at https://github.com/lifeofreilly/ostendo Cheers.